# CSS class and id link styling not working

Tags: html, css

I am self-taught in HTML and CSS, but one problem I have recently been running into is modifying links with CSS. I have done it in the past before, many times with no error, but now all the ways I can think of and that I find on the internet do nothing.

I have tried all of these ways, and none worked:

```html
a.linkclass:link{text-decoration:none;}

.linkclass a:link{text-decoration:none;}

#linkid a:link{text-decoration:none;}

a#linkid:link{text-decoration:none;}
```

{note, these were not done all at the same time, just examples}

My HTML and CSS are as follows(after looking over and over, I could find nothing wrong that could cause these problems)

```css
body{
margin:0;
background-color:eaf7ff;
}

#menubar{
max-height:10%;
min-height:3%
height:5%;
background-color:BBBBBB;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
max-width:100%;
min-width:100%;
width:100%;
float:left;
position:fixed;
display:inline-block
}

#pushbox{
max-height:10%;
height:10%;
background-color:black;
max-width:100%;
min-width:100%;
width:100%;
}

#box1{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}
#tag1{
background-color:eaf7ff;
margin:0;
}

#box2{
background-color:fff7ea;
}
#tag2{
background-color:eaf7ff;
margin:0;
}

#box3{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}
#tag3{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}

#box4{
background-color:fff7ea;
}
#tag4{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}

#box5{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}
#tag5{
background-color:eaf7ff;
}

#copyright{
}

.content{
max-width:100%;
min-width:100%;
width:100%;
min-height:80%;
height:85%;
}

.contenttag{
max-height:10%;
height:10%;
max-width:100%;
min-width:100%;
width:100%;
}

a.menulink{
border:1px solid black;
background-color:red;
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ==========MENUBAR==========-->
<div id='menubar'>
<h1>
<a href='#tag1' class='menulink'>OPT1</a>
<a href='#tag2' class='menulink'>OPT2</a>
<a href='#tag3' class='menulink'>OPT3</a>
<a href='#tag4' class='menulink'>OPT4</a>
<a href='#tag5' class='menulink'>OPT5</a>
</h1>
</div>

<!-- ==========CONTENTBOX1==========-->
<div id='tag1' class='contenttag'></div>
<div id='box1' class='content'>

<h1>ContentBox1</h1>

</div>
<!-- ==========CONTENTBOX2==========-->
<div id='tag2' class='contenttag'></div>
<div id='box2' class='content'>

<h1>ContentBox2</h1>

</div>
<!-- ==========CONTENTBOX3==========-->
<div id='tag3' class='contenttag'></div>
<div id='box3' class='content'>

<h1>ContentBox3</h1>

</div>
<!-- ==========CONTENTBOX4==========-->
<div id='tag4' class='contenttag'></div>
<div id='box4' class='content'>

<h1>ContentBox4</h1>

</div>
<!-- ==========CONTENTBOX5==========-->
<div id='tag5' class='contenttag'></div>
<div id='box5' class='content'>

<h1>ContentBox5</h1>

</div>
<!-- ==========COPYRIGHT==========-->
<div id='copyright'><center>
copyright &copy; Vladimir Plenskiy <?php echo date("Y"); ?>, Template by Timothy Leitzke
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'a.menulink' by itself did not work. (Sorry if this is confusing, it is currently 12:14 AM and I have also been working on a project in Unity and some art on my computer for the past 24+ hours)

--edit--

for those who do not understand what my problem is, even though the format is right. The CSS styling using classes and ids does not work(the examples that I tried are all at the first CSS stylesheet. that style sheet is not one used on the page, as seen in the header, only ONE is used)

Comment: Its working fine, what is the issue? Please be descriptive.

Comment: sorry but i was not able to understand whats the problem. `a.menulink` style does applies to links.

Comment: You've got masses (too much: http://sscce.org/ ) of code (including two stylesheets, one of which uses ID and Class selectors that don't match any ID or Class in the HTML) but no clear problem statement.

Comment: There is only 1 css stylesheet(the other was for examples of what I have tried to use, the first one was that). And the problem is that non of it works. I can only use the 'a:hover{}', and with a class or id- nothign happens.

Comment: @TimLeitzke — When I click "Run code snippet" in your question, the links show up with a black border and a red background. The only selector that applies to that uses a class selector.

Comment: I am running this on my computer though. Edge, explorer and chrome are not showing. I have restarted my mac/windows 10 several time incase it was some error somewhere, but that does not solve it at all.

Comment: @TimLeitzke — Whatever the error is, it doesn't appear in the code you have in your question.

Comment: After my 8th restarting, it is now working. Windows 10 is bringing me a suprising amount of random problems.

Answer (score -2):

According your HTML proper CSS for your links should be:

```
.menulink:link {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: I try this, and the example above stated in the comments, but they do nothing. No changes in background, removal of text-decorations. They just flat out do not work. The format is right, but nothing happens. I am using chrome with windows 10, not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Open your page in your Chrome and press ctrl+shift+i to open DOM inspector. Are there any errors in 'console' tab?